# find : missing argument to -exec

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ubuntu, command-line

I'm trying to execute below move command :

If user wants to overwrite files with same name

```
find /pqr/xyz -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -f {} /abc/def \;
```

If user doesn't want to overwrite files with same name

```
find /pqr/xyz -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -n {} /abc/def \;
```

But Command 2 throws an error saying

```
find : missing argument to -exec
```

While command 1 executes successfully.

Any mistake that i might have done ?

Comment: Typo?  This would happen if the space before `mv` was replaced with a newline.  If Command 1 works, `find` should not complain about `-exec` in Command 2

Comment: This works on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below command

```
find /pqr/xyz -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -f '{}' /abc/def/ \;
```

single quote around {} to handle spaces in file name and it should be /abc/def/ to move files under /abc/def/ directory or else it will rename filename to 'def'

You can also refer to [usage](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm#exec) link

Hope this might help you

Thanks

Comment: The single quotes around `{}` do nothing — try it. `-exec` handles quoting issues automatically. The files won't be named `/abc/def` even without the final slash _if_ the directory already exists.